# Using mathjax in an updating sequence in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, updates, mathjax

I have four dynamic variables in my program,

```
xzero, xone, xtwo, xthree
```

That represent the coefficients of a cubic function. I want to show the actual equation in the HTML, in the following format:

```
xthree*x^3+xtwo*x^2+xone*x+xzero=f(x)
```

but it needs to be able to update with the variables, so I had originally thought that I would do a

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = (new equation);
```

But it seems to me that either mathJax doesn't work in javascript, or that I'm not doing it right. The only alternative solution that I could think of is to make four individual div tags per variable, and update them all, but this seems unnecessarily clunky. Could I get some pointers either way as to how I would fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MathJax automagically renders the document when it is loaded, but not later. Try explicitly requesting re-render:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "...";
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, 'demo']);
```

**EDIT**: After some thinking, I figured you could ask for the render in one element, keep it hidden, then copy the finished markup into another, to prevent flicker:

```js
var mathDiv = document.getElementById('math');
var displayDiv = document.getElementById('display');

MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"math"]);
MathJax.Hub.Queue(function() {
  var math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("MathDiv")[0];
  var i = 1;
  setInterval(function() {
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Text", math, "\\int_0^{" + i + "} x dx"]);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(function() {
      displayDiv.innerHTML = mathDiv.innerHTML;
    });
    i++;
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#math {
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML">
</script>
<div id="math">$$$$</div>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: That seemed to work, but for a brief second, when I update it the equation seems to show as $...$ before rendering. This is causing my page to shudder, so is there any way to fix this?

Comment: No, Update doesn't seem to do anything to rerender it, unfortunately

Comment: Oh. Well, after a bit more thinking, I think this should work then.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.